# Adding Facebook button to top links Magento

Tags: toplinks, facebook

I just haven't been able to get this after reading many examples. I'm trying to add a facebook login button to the top links. I can get thew block to show up all over the place but not in the top links.

This last atempt makes all the links disappear:

```
<reference name="top.links">

    <action method="setTemplate">
        <block type="fblogin/fblogin" name="fblogin" template="fblogin/fblogin.phtml">
        <action method="setAttribute"><key>position</key><value>1</value></action>
        </block>
    </action>
```

fblogin

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I figured something out. This works:

```
        <reference name="top.links">
        <block type="fblogin/fblogin" name="fblogin">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>fblogin/fblogin.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <block type="fblogin/fblogin" name="fblogin" template="fblogin/fblogin.phtml" />
        </block>
        <action method="addLinkBlock">
            <blockName>fblogin</blockName>
        </action>
    </reference>
```